# runAsGroup by group name instead of group id in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

Needed to run a container in k8s with access to a directory and its subdirectories under special group called "xyz" with current Group Id 111. There is an option to either modify the Dockerfile as below:

```
RUN usermod -u 222 myUser \
    && groupmod -g 222 myUser

RUN true \
    && groupadd --gid 111 myGroup \
    && usermod -a -G myGroup myUser
```

But the problem is that Group ID = 111 keeps changing on each OS Update in host nodes, so this breaks the pod and create permission issues. Other way would be to modify helm chart itself as :

```
  securityContext:
      runAsGroup: 111 // fsGroup ?
```

Can we make pod container's User `myUser` be part of a host Group ex: `xyz` by **name** instead of **Id** ?

Comment: When you say "host nodes", what do you mean exactly?  Usually a Kubernetes pod won't care which specific node it's running on, or be bothered with details like specific host user IDs.

Comment: @DavidMaze, meant the worker k8s nodes have a folder structure whose owner is group "xyz" and the container needs to read these logs from the directories. In order to do so, trying to run container as directory's group name since corresponding groupId keeps changing

Comment: any success in your quest? you mentioned helm chart. why you dont stick to this option if it works for you?

Comment: ended up modifying the entrypoint.sh of Dockerfile to lookup groupId. Nodes would export groupId to a metadata URL, from where it will be fetched in entrypoint.sh dynamically